# Rotated text in div corner (45deg) breaks if longer than 6 letters. How to center it forever?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have this code https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/wpyqt71w/

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #fff;
}

.triangle {
  border-left: 7vmax solid red;
  border-bottom: 7vmax solid transparent;
}

.triangle::after {
  content: 'Hello!';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: 0vmax;
  top: 2vmax;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

and everything works good for me.

Now I need to use another word instead of "Hello!" Maybe this word is longer or shorter. How to automatically center using also the font-size variable size?

[image: HELLO!]

[image: HELLO123!]

[image: HEL]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: #fff;
}

.triangle {
    border-left: 7vmax solid red;
    border-bottom: 7vmax solid transparent;
}

.triangle::after {
  content: 'hello!123';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: 2.75vmax;
  top: 1.75vmax;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(315deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a pseudo. You can get the result with the base element alone (and this way the text is in the html).

With a somewhat complex transform, you get the element to auto adapt. Notice that the red background adapts perfectly to the borders. (If you add padding to the triangle, it will also adapt)

I have also set a shadow to fill the corners. I used a distinct color so you can easily see what is the element and waht the shadow.

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    box-shadow: 0px -50px 0px 50px tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle">How are you ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vals, but If I put `display: grid; align-content: center;` on `container` it's a mess! Why? Can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed with `position: absolute` but what when the div is not too high? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/wgyr523a/ I need a version with simply the corner. When the div is small I don't care about text, but I need the red corner. How to?

Comment: Nothing new @vals?

Comment: Dear @vals, what if I need to override the border of the parent div? I need the potato on the grey border of the `container`. Is it possible?

Comment: Dear @vals, can you see this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025290/flexbox-strange-behaviour-with-cssgrid

Comment: @JohnSam I have taken a look. Sorry, just can't help you more than Michael_B. (may be there is no solution ?)

Comment: Dear @vals, your `transform` is great for `top left` corner. But what for other corners: `top right`, `bottom left` and `bottom right`? I don't know how to change `transform`.