# Flexbox, strange behaviour with CSSGrid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have this situation: https://jsfiddle.net/johnsam/rdtva2fq/

On **Chrome** it works good, see this:

[image]

It start (see "FIRST" and "LAST" btn). Good.

On **Safari** it doesn't (also with iPad/iPhone, it's the same) see this:

[image]

"FIRST" btn OK, "LAST" one nope. The page has a scrollbar that is what I don't want!

**If I remove the header part it works good, so my guess is Safari doesn't recognize the (`height: 100vh` MINUS the header part of that height) maybe.
I'm right?**

Code:

```
<div class="my-all d-flex flex-column height100">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background: red;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 my-5">
        Test space long long long
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-main d-flex height100" style="background: cyan;">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex media-body">
      <div class="row my-row my-3">
        <div class="col-6 my-grid">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary my-btn">
            <span>FIRST</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari has a known issue with `vh` units. It doesn't read them correctly . so you could use jQuery for that `$(window).height()` is equal cu 100vh

Comment: This appears to be a bug with Safari. For whatever reason, the button elements are overflowing the parent, and the parent stubbornly refuses to expand to accommodate them. Possibly a conflict between Bootstrap, Grid and Flex. Whatever. This sucks. I tried 45 different adjustments. Nothing worked. See this [**jsfiddle history**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdtva2fq/46/) going back to version /1/. Always worked in Chrome. Never in Safari.

Comment: If anybody sees something I missed, please post and answer or just let me know. Hopefully it wasn't something super simple and easy, cause that would *really* suck. Sorry @JohnSam, I gave it a shot. Good luck.

Comment: It's very sad all this. Can we open a bug for Safari? Where to?

Comment: What if you simply drop the `<div class="my-main d-flex height100" style="background: cyan;"><div class="container-fluid d-flex media-body">` wrappers? ... https://jsfiddle.net/rdtva2fq/48/

Comment: It's not good because the buttons doesn't resize themself anymore.